# Does wscript.exe require a path to a script to work?

Tags: vba, wsh

I have written some code which runs a script using wscript.exe.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

oShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", strPath2Script, , "runas", 1
```

Key to this is the "runas" which allows us to run as an admin.  This all works fine, but I also have to have additional code elsewhere to create a script file.  This seems like a waste, and I would prefer to just send in the code in the file located at strPath2Script as a parameter to wscript.

It doesn't seem like that is possible, and if I have to generate the script, so be it, but is it possible to just send code as a string into wscript.exe rather than have to provide a path to a text file which has the script code?

Thanks for any insights.

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't just pass code into wscript.exe or cscript.exe.  You'll have to write it to a file and pass the filename to wscript.exe or cscript.exe.

Comment: Ok.  It seems like creating a file like this shouldn't be needed because the program goes to the file and gets the code anyway.  I thought there might be a command line switch which says "just take the string as the code itself", but it doesn't seem that way.  Thanks for your response